# Share ground between 12 V and 5 V

Tags: relay, trigger

I am working on this small project getting a relay to turn on/off the amp. when it gets a 12 V trigger from a netstreamer.

The relay is powered from 5 V USB 230 V adapter.

Question: should I connect the ground, -12 V, to the same ground as the 5 V power supplier?

**EDIT**
https://www.electrokit.com/uploads/productfile/41015/41015704_-_5V_Relay_Module.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the relay.

Comment: @jsotola diagram updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally yes - otherwise, no closed circuit is created which could trigger your relay.

Make sure your relay module supports a 12V signal though, and always take the necessary precautions when working with high voltages.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is an (optical) isolator somewhere in the relay circuit, the 5V and 12V parts should share the same ground. **But** you should make sure the relay circuit can handle the +12V input signal.

It would help if you could tell us what relay module you're using and what the trigger source is.

Comment: See edit post. The Trigger source is a network streamer that has a 12v mono jack out to turn the amplifier on when the streamer is turned on, but in my case the amp. does not have a trigger in .

Comment: Why would an opto isolator make a difference?

Comment: Optical isolators allow you to transfer signals from one circuit to another without the need for a common ground.